# how to move background images continously cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am fairly new to cocos2D and i am experiencing a problem that made me stuck on my game development. I have to background images, one is an image of a road and the other one is of footpath, what i want is to move the road image faster than the footpath image? How can i accomplish this task? 
Please help.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`CCParallaxNode`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-alpha/interface_c_c_parallax_node.html). It's part of cocos2d.

Comment: Thanx for your quick response, will look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
id roadMovementAction = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration 0.5f position: ccp(-32,0)];

id footPathMovementAction = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration 1.0f position: ccp(-32,0)];

[roadImage runAction: roadMovementAction];

[footPathImage runAction: footPathMovementAction];
```

Basically you're just moving the background images -32 pixels on the x axis... 
quite simple :)

you also might want to chuck in an if statement so when the images leave the screen it replaces them and repeats or whatever it is you're trying to do :)

hope that helped